# Pipe to less but keep the highlighting

Tags: pipe, syntax-highlighting, less, highlighting

Is it possible to pipe output (e.g. `dmesg`) to a command like `less` (or equivalent) and keep the text highlighting used by the original command?

example: on the left `dmesg | less` on the right `dmesg`

[image: <code>dmesg | less</code> vs <code>dmesg</code>]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the `--human` parameter to view colored `dmesg` output in a `less`-like environment.

```
dmesg --human --color=always
```

Or use the short version:

```
dmesg -H
```

Alternatively, use the following command to achieve similar results.

```
dmesg --color=always | less -R
```

Many other utilities that produce colored output (`ls`, `grep`, etc.) have a similar  `--color=always` option.

Comment: Actually `--human` does more than just preserve color and pipe to `less`: it also marks dates as e.g. `[May23 00:58]` and subsequent small offsets as `[  +6.046768]` instead of what would always be `[121187.191521]` with `less`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this preserving of color formatting automatic for anytime I'm piping *any* txt based command (not just dmesg)?

Comment: @mikemtnbikes You have to use the `--color=always` if provided by the program. A program knows if it is outputting to a pipe and can therefore decide to output color or not.

Comment: `git` also has the `--color=always` option

Comment: `dmesg -H -T` gives absolute timestamps, e.g. `[Sat Jul  3 02:39:08 2021]` instead of `[  +0.000002]`

Answer (score 2):

A generic command to preserve coloration independent of the program providing the output is the `unbuffer` command (which is part of the `expect` package).

Usage:

```
unbuffer dmesg | less -R
```

Comment: Given that the OP uses `dmesg` as an example, **this should be the accepted answer**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works nice.

- for tree:
  `tree -C | less -r`
- for ls:
  `ls -lA --color=always | less -r`
- for pytest:
  `py.test --color=yes | less -r`